# Are Windows filesystem paths using the volume GUID invalid without the long path prefix?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

As quoted from the win32 docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-volume):

> You must specify full paths when using volume GUID paths with the "\\?\" prefix.

Now, we have had a bit of a discussion about this in my team over whether this means that volume GUID paths cannot be used without the prefix, or that when using "full" (long?) paths with volume GUIDs, you should use the prefix to do so.

The second interpretation seems to be incorrect, as using any of the Windows API will only succeed with the prefix before the guid.

For example:

```
    std::wstring path = L"\\\\?\\Volume{fe31c178-7b35-4b43-9899-1dcd701d938a}\\Test\\";

    bool success = CreateDirectoryW(path.c_str(), NULL);
```

`success` will only be `true` if the `\\?\` prefix is in `path`.

Our issue comes in using a third-party File Driver that is giving us paths without that prefix. If it is explicitly invalid to use volume GUID paths without this prefix, then I would like to be letting them know of this bug. Otherwise we'll just handle the case on our end.

Comment: without \\?\ prefix win32 wrong convert path to nt path. so \\?\ must be always used with volume path

Comment: Without using an explicit device path (prefixed by "\\?\", "\\.\", "//?/", "//./", etc), only DOS drives and classic DOS device names (e.g. NUL, CON, AUX, PRN, COM1, LPT1 -- and also CONIN$ and CONOUT$) are accessible. Otherwise using relative filenames would be unreliable.